# Using interpolation within an attribute name (avoiding eval)

Tags: ruby, attributes, string-interpolation

I'm defining my own method that will allow me to update multiple attributes of a given object to that of another object `new_car`. Many of the attributes have similar names such as "entered_text_1", "entered_text_2", "entered_text_3" up to "entered_text_10" (In the example below I've just done up to 3 to illustrate).

**Problem**

Wondering how to use interpolation within an attribute name itself, such as `car.entered_text_"#{i}"`
(which is not correct)

**Desired Outcome**

The below code works and does what I'm looking for, however I've seen numerous warning about using `eval` - and I'm wondering what the better alternative is in this scenario?

```
# class Car and class NewCar exist with the same attribute names (:entered_text_1, :entered_text_2, :entered_text_3)

def self.copy_attributes(car, new_car)
  i = 1
  until i > 3
    eval("car.entered_text_#{i} = new_car.entered_text_#{i}")
    puts eval("car.entered_text_#{i}")
    i += 1
  end

end

current_car = Car.new('White', 'Huge', 'Slow')
golf = NewCar.new('Red', 'Small', 'Fast')

copy_attributes(current_car, golf)

# => Red, Small, Fast
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the fact that assignments like `user.name = 'John'` are actually method calls and can be written like this: `user.name=('John')`, where `name=` is the name of the method. We can invoke methods dynamically with `send` (call any method) or `public_send` (call a public method, will raise error if method exists but is private).

```
car.public_send("entered_text_#{i}=", new_car.public_send("entered_text_#{i}"))
puts car.public_send("entered_text_#{i}")
```

Comment: Ah perfect, that's the sort of thing I was looking for. Looks like the parenthesis should be updated ```car.send(("entered_text_#{i}="), new_car.send("entered_text_#{i}"))``` for it to work but it does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @rpg: ah right, forgot one closing parenthesis. thanks for spotting. You don't need to parenthesize a string by itself (the first argument)

Comment: I would like to suggest `public_send` instead of `send`.